# cloning a List of a Base class

Tags: java, netbeans, clone

I have a base class called AddressType

I also have two child classes called HouseholdAddressType, PersonalAddressType.
(so the these both extends AddressType)

i pass around a list of AddressType:

```
List<AddressType> addresses
```

to many method, and preform varies tasks, thus I want to clone this list before I preform these tasks..

I attempted this:

```
List<AddressType> copyOfAddress = new ArrayList<AddressType>(addresses.size());
    for (AddressType addressType: addresses) {
        copyOfAddress.add((AddressType)addressType.clone());         
    }
```

however it does not work stating that: "clone has protected access"

how can I make a clone of this list?
examples with my class names would be good.. Thanks so much

Comment: What exactly is saying 'clone has protected access' ?

Comment: Also, have you implemented clone itself? Otherwise you're performing a shallow copy and not a deep copy, you should implement cloneable and rewrite clone

Answer (score 3):

The class `AddressType` must implement the `Cloneable` interface,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Person> oldList = new ArrayList<Person>(1);
        oldList.add(new Person("Harry", "Potter"));

        List<Person> newList = new ArrayList<Person>();
        for(Person person : oldList)
        {
            newList.add(person.clone()); // Deep copy of each person too.
        }

        Person person = newList.get(0);
        person.setFirstName("James");

        System.out.println("Old list = " + oldList);
        System.out.println("New list = " + newList);
    }

    static class Person implements Cloneable
    {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;

        Person(String firstName, String lastName)
        {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        private Person(Person person)
        {
            this.firstName = person.firstName;
            this.lastName = person.lastName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName)
        {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getFirstName()
        {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName)
        {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String getLastName()
        {
            return lastName;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.append(firstName);
            sb.append(" ");
            sb.append(lastName);

            return sb.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public Person clone()
        {
            return new Person(this);
        }
    }
}
```

outputs

```
Old list = [Harry Potter]
New list = [James Potter]
```

Comment: This is probably the best solution since it is utilizing the copy constructor collections have. If I'm not mistaken unless his class implements Cloneable it will not perform a deep copy.

Comment: Right, but if he does not implement cloneable the list will not be deep copied but rather shallow copied, the clone method of object will be called since it was not overriden...

clone in java is not broken, it just isn't perfect

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, You are absolutely right. If OP does not implement the `Cloneable` interface and override the `clone` method, deep copies of the list contents will not be made, although a deep copy of the list itself will be made.

Comment: In this particular example, because `Person` only contains Strings, and strings are immutable, your `clone()` method can simply do: `public Person clone() { return (Person) super.clone(); }` (plus the `CloneNotSupportedException` handling).